# Image not updating in phantom Wallet

Tags: anchor, rust, candy-machine-v2, metaboss

I have updated NFT metadata which is successfully updated on `explorer.solana.com` and `solscan.io` and a new image is showing up. Phantom wallet is still showing the old image. What could be the issue?

Comment: Same issue for more than 6 hours. Not sure how to invalidate the cache.

Comment: I used ```metaboss``` to update the NFTS. ```https://metaboss.rs/update.html```